# Correct Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Assumed, the following derivative should be calculated:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}} \sum_{t=0}^\infty\lambda_t(k_t - k_{t+1})$

Because of a discussion I had, I am interested in knowing two things:

1. Is the way in which the derivative is stated mathematically correct?
2. What is the mathematically correct solution to this? (irrespective of whether the derivative is stated correctly)

Some thoughts:

When looking at the sum, it becomes clear that a specific $k_{t+1}$ is contained exactly two times in it. Thus, the "logical" solution would be $= -\lambda_t + \lambda_{t+1}$. However, I think it is not correct to state the derivative in the way it is stated above. Simply solving the stated derivative as it is would lead to the solution $= \sum_{t=0}^\infty-\lambda_t$.

Comment: The main problem is that you use the same variable $t$ for two different purposes, once outside the sum and once inside. A variable $t$ used outside of the sum cannot be used as the summation index at the same time. The summation index is not a fixed value, it "runs" through all non-negative numbers, while the $t$ used outside of the sum must be some fixed value that specifies which partial derivative we are interested in. Clarify what you are actually looking for. If it something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial k_m}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\ldots$, the question is easy to answer.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thank you for your answer! In order to clarify what I am looking for: the derivative of the sum for an arbitrary $k_{t+1}$. the time step $t$ should still appear in the solution as I don't want to get an expression simply for a single concrete time step (e.g. $t = 1$) but for an arbitrary "$t$". I would be very interested in how you would rewrite the derivative or sum to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \lambda_t\big(k_t-k_{t+1}\big)\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
is certainly problematic, if only because its meaning is not entirely clear, and I'm sure some of my former colleagues would insist that it is *incorrect*. Although I would never use an expression like (\ref{e1}) myself (except inadvertently), however, neither would I argue with anyone who tried to defend it as merely being synonymous with
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{s+1}\big)\tag{2}\label{e2}\ ,
$$
a quite unambiguous expression, to which I don't believe anyone would object to as being incorrect. The problem with expression (\ref{e1}) is that the same symbol $\ \text{"$t$"}\ $ is used both as a genuine free variable (in $\ \partial k_{t+1}\ $) and as a dummy variable (within the scope of the sum $\ \sum_\limits{t=0}^\infty\ $), which might raise some doubt as to whether the author *really* intended the expression to be synonymous with (\ref{e2}), or perhaps instead with
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_t-k_{t+1}\big),\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{t+1}\big)\ ,
$$
or something else entirely.

Even if expression (\ref{e1}) is regarded as synonymous with (\ref{e2}) it would be quite confusing and error-prone to try to evaluate it in that form, whereas evaluation of the expression (\ref{e2}) is quite straightforward.  If $\ t=-1\ ,$ then $\ k_{t+1}=k_0\ ,$ and that variable appears in just one term of the sum $\ \sum_\limits{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{s+1}\big)\ ,$ namely that for $\ s=0\ ,$$\ \lambda_0(k_0-k_1)\ $. Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_0}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{s+1}\big)=\lambda_0\ .
$$
If, on the other hand, $\ t\ge0\ ,$ then $\ k_{t+1}\ $ appears in exactly *two* terms of the sum$\ \sum_\limits{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{s+1}\big)\ ,$ namely that for $\ s=t\ ,$$\ \lambda_t(k_t-k_{t+1})\ $ and that for $\ s=t+1\ ,$$\ \lambda_{t+1}\big(k_{t+1}-k_{t+2}\big)\ .$ Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial k_{t+1}}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \lambda_s\big(k_s-k_{s+1}\big)=\lambda_{t+1}-\lambda_t\ .
$$